# Print mirror image of 2D array of characters

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Please check the problem with this code.
It is showing compilation error when I'm running it on mycodeschool IDE. 
problem statement is
Problem statement
Given a two dimensional array, print its mirror image if mirror is placed along one of the sides of the array.

Input
First line of input will contain a number T = number of test cases. Each test case will contain two positive integers n and m (1<=n, m<=50) on a single line separated by space. Next n lines will each contain a string of exactly m characters. Next line will contain a character 'V' or 'H'. If character is V, mirror is placed vertically along the right-most column. If the character is H, the mirror is placed horizontally along the bottom-most row.

Output
For each test case, print the n*m mirror image - n lines with strings of m character each. Print an extra empty line after output for each test case.

Sample Input
2
3 3
abc
def
ghi
V
3 4
1234
5678
9876
H
Sample Output
cba
fed
ihg

9876
5678
1234

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char a[10][10];
    int i,j,t,m,n;
    char s;
    scanf("%d\n",&t);
    for(j=0;j<t;j++)
    {
    scanf("%d%d\n",&m,&n);

    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",&a[i]);
    }

    scanf("\n%c",&s);
    if(s=='V')//for image along rightmost vertical line
    {
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            strrev(a[i]);
        }

    }  
    else if(s=='H')//for image along lowermost horizontal line
    {
        int t=0;
        int b=m-1;
        while(t<b)
            {
                char *temp = (char *)malloc((strlen(a[t]) + 1) *   sizeof(char));//temporary variable to swap
                strcpy(temp, a[t]);
                strcpy(a[t], a[b]);
                strcpy(a[b], temp);
                free(temp);
                t++;
                b--;
            }
        }

for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    printf("%s\n",a[i]);
}
printf("\n");}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: compiler showing these errors                                                            solution.c: In function ‘main’:
solution.c:17:3: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[10]’ [-Wformat]
solution.c:25:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strrev’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
/tmp/ccakP84K.o: In function `main':
solution.c:(.text+0xe4): undefined reference to `strrev'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with taking input character array n line with exactly m characters...here is my code ........

```
int main()
{
    int tt,i,j,r,c,t,ch;
    char a[20][20];
    scanf("%d",&t);

    for(tt=1;tt<=t;t++)
    {
        scanf("%d\t%d",&r,&c);

        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<c;j++)
            {
                scanf("%c",&a[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        scanf("%c",&ch);

        if(ch=='V')
        {
            for(i=0;i<r;i++)
            {
                for(j=(c-1);j>=0;j--)
                {
                    printf("%d",a[i][j]);
                    printf("\t");
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        else if(ch=='H')
        { 
            for(i=(r-1);i>=0;i--)
            {
                for(j=0;j<c;j++)
                {
                    printf("%d",a[i][j]);
                    printf("\t");
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        else
            printf("error");
    }
    printf("");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```